# js $.post issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following js code

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#filterSub').click(function (evt) {
        var data = $('form').serialize();
        var gender = $('#gender').html();

        $.post('data.php', {
            data,
            gender: gender
        }, function (resultp) {
            $('#List').html(resultp);
        });
        $.post('filter.php', {
            data,
            gender: gender
        }, function (result) {
            $('.addFilter').html(result);
        });
        //              alert(gender);

        //return false;
    });
});
```

I am using

```
parse_str($_POST['data'],$_POST);
```

Which works perfectly fine and I am getting the form variables.

However, I am trying to get the variable 'gender' in my PHP script with

```
 $_POST['gender']
```

in PHP. But it is not getting anything. (setting an alert in the script for 'gender' pops up the correct value)

Also, is there any way I can send both the post queries in one command to the different files? The data being sent is the same.

I am bad at JS so I feel there is an elementary mistake that I am making in the $.post request format.

Any help will be appreciated as I already have spent an entire day on this without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `parse_str($_POST['data'], $_POST);` replaces the `$_POST` array with the result of parsing the `data` parameter -- any existing entries in the array are lost. So you're losing `$_POST['gender']`.

You could parse it into a different array:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);
```

or you could extract the `gender` parameter into a variable before you call `parse_str()`.

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);
```

Another option is to get rid of the `data` parameter entirely, just post the serialized fields as separate parameters.

```
    var data = $('form').serialize();
    var gender = $('#gender').html();
    var params = data + '&gender=' + encodeURIComponent(gender);
    $.post('data.php', params, function (resultp) {
        $('#List').html(resultp);
    });
```

Comment: You got it, Barmar ! Thanks for saving my day ! BTW, could you also tell me if I can make single request to submit to two files ?

Comment: No you can't submit to two different URLs in one request.